# How do I add a field/column from a subquery into the outer select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and have been learning on my own for a couple of months.

I have a subquery with multiple joins.  The where clause in the subquery is for one of the joins and I have added that field/column to my outer select statement with no issues.  My problem is, I need to include a field/column from one of the other joins in the subquery.  How do I do that?  Just adding it to the outer select statement gives a "could not be bound" error.

Here is my subquery:

```
(select cn.UniqContactName 
 from ContactName cn
 join ContactNumber cnu on cn.UniqContactName = cnu.UniqContactName
 join ContactClass cc on cn.UniqContactName = cc.UniqContactName
 join LkContactClass lkcc on lkcc.UniqLkContactClass = cc.UniqLkContactClass
 join ConfigureLkLanguageResource lr on lr.ConfigureLkLanguageResourceID = lkcc.ConfigureLkLanguageResourceID and lr.CultureCode = 'en-US'

 where lr.ResourceText like '%Opt Out - Electronic Communication%'
 )
```

I want to add a field/column from the ContactNumber table to my outer select statement.

Comment: observation: your first join is serving no purpose. You are joining a table on itself with the same column.

Comment: [Have you seen this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks, Crowcoder. I had previously read that but missed the info re adding fields from table in subquery joins; ie. - all tables must be in outer join.  As to the first join it is not on itself.  I am joining ContactNAME on ContactNUMBER - different tables.

Comment: My eyes did not read it that way for some reason but now I see

Comment: Also, if I join the  ContactNumber table to the outer select statement my data bloats.

Comment: I assume by "bloat" you mean you are getting more rows than expected. Think about this example: you have a table of Countries and a table of Continents. If you join them you will get a row for every country and continent combination. That's how it works. You might be able to condense your result with DISTINCT or GROUP  BY but of course I can't know that with the given info.

Comment: I had already tried Distinct and it didn't give me the needed results.  I left the join in my outer select statement and added an additional condition in the where clause.  That was what I needed!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can change subquery to outer apply in my opinion.

like :

```
select .....
from ....
OUTER APPLY (select cn.UniqContactName 
 from ContactName cn
 join ContactNumber cnu on cn.UniqContactName = cnu.UniqContactName
 join ContactClass cc on cn.UniqContactName = cc.UniqContactName
 join LkContactClass lkcc on lkcc.UniqLkContactClass = cc.UniqLkContactClass
 join ConfigureLkLanguageResource lr on lr.ConfigureLkLanguageResourceID = lkcc.ConfigureLkLanguageResourceID and lr.CultureCode = 'en-US'

 where lr.ResourceText like '%Opt Out - Electronic Communication%'
 ) as OA
```